# Problema CORS con fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch, cors

Obtengo el siguiente error al intentar utilizar una API de Google Map en Javascript con fetch

> Pedido de origen cruzado bloqueado: La política de mismo origen no permite leer el recurso remoto

Aclaro que en POSTMAN me trae el resultado correctamente, que es un json

En el código javascript intento hacer el fetch a la API de prueba https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1 y me trae el resultado correctamente

Cómo podría solucionar este inconveniente ? ya he probado varias cosas sin resultado.

Gracias!

```
fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536%2C-104.9847034&key=key')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch( err => console.error(err));
```

Aclaro que ya intenté agregando los headers Allow

```
 headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
},
```

obteniendo el mismo resultado

Comment: Me parece algo raro que esté sucediendo esto, ya que probé a enviar la petición al mismo sitio en un API Tester y funciona correctamente. Por otro lado, que especifiques la cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` desde el cliente no sirve de nada, ya que el servidor es que específica desde qué orígenes puede recibir peticiones y el cliente no.

Comment: ¿Estás haciendo la petición desde un origen con protocolo seguro (https)? Si no, probablemente esa sea la causa del error.

Comment: La verdad que he probado de todo, ya no sé que hacer, no me funciona, problema de google maps no creo que sea, lo prové desde un servidor https y tampco funciona, le saque el header y tampco... leí por ahí que agregando mode: 'no-cors' funcionaba, pero me arroja un error 0, el cual leí que siempre me arrojaría eso si pongo ese mode 'no-cors' , por lo tanto ya no sé que más hacer

Comment: El error continúa siendo:

Comment: Access to fetch at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536%2C-104.9847034&key=key' from origin 'https://www.climt.com.ar' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.